# Convert DateTime From String In C#

Tags: c#

I use the following code for convert the date from String

```
        string JoiningDate="30/11/2013";
        string[] dateconvert = JoiningDate.Split('/');
        string newdate = dateconvert[1] + '/' + dateconvert[0] + '/' + dateconvert[2];
        DateTime JoinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(newdate);
```

My System Date Format is:07/01/14.But I have the Following Error.

```
 String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Then I change My system format is 01-jul-2014.It was working Fine.

Now,How to convert the date from string without consider the system Format?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx), specify the format, and specify the invariant culture to make it absolutely non-system-dependent:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(If you're able to choose this format yourself, I'd use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead, e.g. 2013-11-30. That's ISO-8601 compliant, and is clear to anyone technical... whereas something like 07/01/2014 looks like January 7th to lots of people in the world...)

Comment: Instead of answering, you should be closing this as a dupe!